# boto3 gives error when trying to stop an AWS EC2 instance using Ansible

Tags: python, docker, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to create an ansible playbook to install docker & docker-compose on the host server, **stop and start the AWS EC2 instance** and then restart docker.

Everything goes well until I try to stop the instance, then this happens:

```
TASK [docker_setup : Gather facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: The 'ec2_instance_facts' module has been renamed to 'ec2_instance_info'. This feature will be removed in version 2.13. Deprecation warnings can be 
disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
fatal: [172.31.25.50]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "boto3 required for this module"}
```

Those steps to stop the instance look like this on the playbook:

```
- name: Install boto3 and botocore with pip3 module for Gather facts
  pip:
    name:
      - boto3
      - botocore
    executable: pip-3.7

- name: Gather facts
  action: ec2_instance_facts

- name: Stop myserver instance
  local_action:
    module: ec2
    region: "{{region}}"
    instance_ids: "{{ansible_ec2_instance_id}}"
    state: stopped
```

The reason I installed boto3 is because it was complaining for not being installed but even when installed it still gives an error. I also read around the Internet that I should add `ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python` on the `host` file next to each host and so I did. But it didn`t work. It looks like this:

```
[webservers]
172.31.25.50 ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: How did you decide that `/usr/bin/python` was the correct interpreter to use ? Is it pointing to python 3.7 i.e. the same python that is used by `php-3.7` since this is where you installed ?

Comment: Please make use of [the search feature](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bansible%5D+boto3+required) during your stay in the Stack Exchange network, because this error is very common and always has the same cause

Comment: @Zeitounator thank you for the reply. I just found it on the internet. If I use `/usr/bin/python3.7` other tasks before that one (for example the yum update task), fail because `python2 bindings for rpm are needed for the module`. What would you do?

Comment: @mdaniel I searched on StackOverflow and thats how I found how to stop the instance, then how to install boto3 and then ansible interpreter for the hosts. Apologies if it looks like I didn´t but it is because I haven´t found an answer or the answers that are out there I dont understand, that I asked

Comment: Install in python 2.7...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to solve this:

Instead of using the `ansible_python_interpreter` in the hosts file, I learned that you can actually add it to a specific action of the task via vars:

```
- name: Stop instance(s)
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  ec2_instance:
    aws_access_key: xxxxx
    aws_secret_key: xxxxx
    region: "{{region}}"
    instance_ids: "{{ansible_ec2_instance_id}}"
    state: stopped
```

Also used `python3` instead of `python` on the `ansible_python_interpreter`. If I used `ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3` on the hosts file as I was doing, it would give another error because the default interpreter for the whole task was using it, but this way you can direct it to when you want to use it.

Comment: As explained, this always goes down to which python version you target. There were more solutions to play with the interpreter path: use python 2.7 everywhere and install the boto* libraries there, use python3 by default and downgrade to python2.7 on your yum talks....